How to replace text using a regular expression in bash
Imagine you have the following partial log of a network request (in this case it's an from an iSO app). In this specific example I want to replace the values of the Authorization and X-Client-Secret headers using ONE regular expression in Bash so we can share the log without exposing any secrets:
Http: createRide (422): http(serviceResponse: POST https://staging.test.com/sometpath {
   ["Authorization": "Bearer xxxxxxxxxx", "X-REQUEST-ID": "5FE8D9C0-B3F0-4DAE-9188-A0CB1906EB5D", "X-Client-Version": "3.0.0", "X-Client-Identifier": "something", "Content-Type": "application/json", "X-Api-Version": "1", "X-Client-Secret": "xxxxxxxxx"]
 }
  {
  "data" : {
  }

The regex should work as follows:
Find the header fields that contain either the name secret or authorization, ideally case insensitive and replace its value by e.g. ***.
The result should look as follows:
Http: createRide (422): http(serviceResponse: POST https://staging.test.com/sometpath {
   ["Authorization": "***", "X-REQUEST-ID": "5FE8D9C0-B3F0-4DAE-9188-A0CB1906EB5D", "X-Client-Version": "3.0.0", "X-Client-Identifier": "something", "Content-Type": "application/json", "X-Api-Version": "1", "X-Client-Secret": "***"]
 }
  {
  "data" : {
  }


What have you tried? How well did it work? What did it do wrong?

Or cofigure the web server correctly. This verbose log type is illegal in production in many jurisdictions. It is ok in a development environment (non production) but then there is no reason to mask test credentials and with dependency injection and proper unit tests you don't need credentials either.

Updated the answer. Server config does not help here since it ts the log of a network request sent by our iOS app and the request is build on that app. Also these are debug logs. So everything fne from that perspective.

This should work
masked_log=$(echo "$log" | sed -E 's/(Authorization|Secret)":\s*"[^"]*"/\1": "***"/Ig')

